# Unity AnimatedPropertyUtility.cs' is a binary file instead of a text file When creating new project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im creating new project in Unity. Unity says that the project has compile errors and asked me to launch it in safe mode. After I got this error.

```
error CS2015: 'D:/path/to/project/Editor/Utilities/AnimatedPropertyUtility.cs' is a binary file instead of a text file
```

I've tried to reinstall my unity version and tried to open AnimatedPropertyUtility.cs. VSCode says that it's binary file and can't be displayed in editor.

When I installed it first time like 5 days ago it worked without problem. But today when I tried to create new project. It displayed this error

I thought that unity creates this file in binary format.

I didn't find any solutions on the Internet no matter how much I searched

**Im using unity 2021.2.17f1**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would share more details like your PATH variable or the contents of that file `AnimatedPropertyUtility.cs`. More details help the community to answer :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: that's the problem. This is the file that unity creates when creating a project. And for some reason he created it in binary format and not in text.